# Xamarin Forms Entry: Use comma as decimal separator

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to use a comma as decimal separator in an Xamarin Forms entry with numeric keyboard. I set the Culture to `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("de-DE");` and the `,` is shown on the keyboard, but the entry only accepts `.` as separator and this only works if I use the telephone keyboard. This seems to be an Andoid Bug. Is there a solution for Xamarin Forms?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is.

In order to have it working properly, i would suggest you do the following:

In your shared code create a new class called "NumericInput", deriving from Entry:

```
public class NumericInput : Entry
{
    public static BindableProperty AllowNegativeProperty = BindableProperty.Create("AllowNegative", typeof(bool), typeof(NumericInput), false, BindingMode.TwoWay);
    public static BindableProperty AllowFractionProperty = BindableProperty.Create("AllowFraction", typeof(bool), typeof(NumericInput), false, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public NumericInput()
    {
        this.Keyboard = Keyboard.Numeric;
    }

    public bool AllowNegative
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowNegativeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AllowNegativeProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool AllowFraction
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(AllowFractionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AllowFractionProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then in your android project create a custom renderer for it:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NumericInput), typeof(NumericInputRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.Droid.Renderer
{
public class NumericInputRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    public NumericInputRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {

    }

    private EditText _native = null;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement == null)
            return;

        _native = Control as EditText;
        _native.InputType = Android.Text.InputTypes.ClassNumber;
        if ((e.NewElement as NumericInput).AllowNegative == true)
            _native.InputType |= InputTypes.NumberFlagSigned;
        if ((e.NewElement as NumericInput).AllowFraction == true)
        {
            _native.InputType |= InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
            _native.KeyListener = DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance(string.Format("1234567890{0}", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator));
        }
        if (e.NewElement.FontFamily != null)
        {
            var font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, e.NewElement.FontFamily);
            _native.Typeface = font;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (_native == null)
            return;

        if (e.PropertyName == NumericInput.AllowNegativeProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            if ((sender as NumericInput).AllowNegative == true)
            {
                // Add Signed flag
                _native.InputType |= InputTypes.NumberFlagSigned;
            }
            else
            {
                // Remove Signed flag
                _native.InputType &= ~InputTypes.NumberFlagSigned;
            }
        }
        if (e.PropertyName == NumericInput.AllowFractionProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            if ((sender as NumericInput).AllowFraction == true)
            {
                // Add Decimal flag
                _native.InputType |= InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
                _native.KeyListener = DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance(string.Format("1234567890{0}", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator));
            }
            else
            {
                // Remove Decimal flag
                _native.InputType &= ~InputTypes.NumberFlagDecimal;
                _native.KeyListener = DigitsKeyListener.GetInstance(string.Format("1234567890"));
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

this will create an entry element, which automatically uses the correct decimal separator depending on the current culture setting of the device.

since the class allows for some detailed settings, I should also add the iOS renderer:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NumericInput), typeof(NumericInputRenderer))]
namespace MyApp.iOS.Renderer
{
public class NumericInputRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    private UITextField _native = null;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.NewElement == null)
            return;

        _native = Control as UITextField;

        _native.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;

        if ((e.NewElement as NumericInput).AllowNegative == true && (e.NewElement as NumericInput).AllowFraction == true)
        {
            _native.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation;
        } 
        else if ((e.NewElement as NumericInput).AllowNegative == true)
        {
            _native.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumbersAndPunctuation;
        }
        else if ((e.NewElement as NumericInput).AllowFraction == true)
        {
            _native.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.DecimalPad;
        }
        else
        {
            _native.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad;
        }
        if (e.NewElement.FontFamily != null)
        {
            e.NewElement.FontFamily = e.NewElement.FontFamily.Replace(".ttf", "");
        }
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        if (_native == null)
            return;
    }
}
}
```

However keep in mind that some vendors have implemented custom soft keyboards (i am looking at you, Samsung!), that don't even show a comma as a decimal seperator. In that case the only solution is to install another keyboard, such as SwiftKey or Gboard. However, if a comma is shown, you should be able to use it with the code above.

Comment: The comma is shown on the Keyboard. But I still can't use it as separator with this solution. For example, if I want to type `1,5`, I can type `1,` but when I type the `5`, the number is formatted to `15`. `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` is correctly set to comma.

Comment: So the text in your entry is "1,5", right? 
Then you probably have a parsing issue due to mixed settings.
When retrieving your result,try specifying the current culture for double parsing:

double.Parse(myEntry.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture). 

If double.parse interprets the double format as non-german due to some funny system locale settings, you will "correctly" get 15 out of the parsing if you enter "1,5".

Also vice versa, if I parse "1.5" on a german phone, I would also get 15 from that.

Comment: I added a decimal converter to solve the parsing issue. Now your solution works fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: Brilliant! Just one word to add: Users might still use the clipboard to paste decimal strings like "1,5". I would suggest to bind user input to string properties and use int.TryParse inside the property's setter to check if the entered value really is a proper integer number.